# v$sqlarea: why is elapsed_time less than user_io_time + cpu_time?

Tags: oracle, performance

When running:

```
select user_io_wait_time, cpu_time, elapsed_time, user_io_wait_time + cpu_time
from v$sqlarea where /* filter */
```

I get the output as below. Can you please explain why the sum of cpu_time and user_io_wait_time is greater than the elapsed_time? I thought elapsed_time would be the total time spent on the query including user_io, cpu, system io, concurrency etc.. All returned rows represent long-running update statements. Oracle 10g. Thanks, Thomas.

```
USER_IO_WAIT    CPU_TIME    ELAPSED_TIME    USER_IO_WAIT+CPU_TIME
721189651        32450000      742860743    753639651
719109237        32540000      740826171    751649237
720330754        32540000      741987150    752870754
725473348        32670000      747215507    758143348
720799316        32540000      742501530    753339316
725361991        33000000      747416902    758361991
725387023        32830000      747236752    758217023
720383321        32210000      741849457    752593321
```

Answer (score 2):

`ELAPSED_TIME` is just `elapsed time used by the cursor for parsing, executing, and fetching`.

`CPU_TIME` is the `CPU time (in microseconds) used by this cursor for parsing, executing, and fetching`

Apparently `CPU_TIME` does not consist of user io time, concurrency and application wait time etc. in the same way and `USER_IO` time do not account for cpu time, concurrency and application wait time etc. and it is pretty difficult (but not impossible) to find out the components of `ELAPSED_TIME`.

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2129.htm) should give you a fair idea of `v$sqlarea`.